# database query - array which does not include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an array stored in element in DB.
Currently using:

```
Item.where("something && ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", [1,2])
```

Which gives me the Items where the 'something' includes either a 1 or 2.

However, I need to find the items where the 'something' doesn't include either a 1 or a 2...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to use the `where.not` clause

`Item.where.not("something && ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", [1,2])`